# Does the integral $\int _0^\infty \frac 1{1+(x \cos x)^2}\,dx$ converge?

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

#### Question

$$\int _0^\infty \frac 1{1+(x \cos x)^2}dx$$
Does this converge?

#### Thoughts

Tried bounding it with $\frac 1{\cos^2x}$ for $x>1$ but not much success.

Comment: Please tell us why you chose this completely misleading title.

Comment: I'm sorry, I mistyped the desired integral..

Comment: @user1685224: The calculus police will be arriving at your door shortly.

Comment: Too much hours of calculus inflict my concentration. Sorry again

Comment: Note that the integrand is $\ge 1$ everywhere, so the integral must be infinity.

Comment: are you sure (for the first integral?)

Answer (score 4):

Note that

- $(x \cos x)^{2} \leq n^{2}\pi^{2} \cos^{2} x$ on each interval $[(n-1)\pi, n\pi]$, and
- $\sin^{2} x \leq x^{2} $ for any $x$.

So it follows that

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1+(x \cos x)^{2}}
&\geq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{dx}{1+n^{2}\pi^{2}\cos^{2} x}
 = 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{dx}{1+n^{2}\pi^{2}\sin^{2} x} \\
&\geq 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{dx}{1+n^{2}\pi^{2}x^{2}} \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{n\pi} \int_{0}^{n\pi^{2}/2} \frac{dx}{1+x^{2}} \qquad (n\pi x \mapsto x)
\end{align*}

But since

$$ \frac{2}{\pi} \int_{0}^{n\pi^{2}/2} \frac{dx}{1+x^{2}} \xrightarrow[]{n\to\infty} 1, $$

by the Limit Comparison Test we have

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{n\pi} \int_{0}^{n\pi^{2}/2} \frac{dx}{1+x^{2}} = \infty. $$

This proves the divergence of the integral.

---

A little bit elaborated argument shows that, for $N\pi \leq x \leq (N+1)\pi$, we have

$$ \int_{0}^{x} \frac{dt}{1+(t \cos t)^{2}} = \sum_{n=1}^{N} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{2 \, dt}{1+n^{2}\pi^{2}\sin^{2} t} + O(1) $$

By observing the following identity

$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{dt}{1+a^{2}\sin^{2} t} = \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{a^{2}+1}}, $$

it follows that

$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{2 \, dt}{1+n^{2}\pi^{2}\sin^{2} t} = \frac{1}{n} + O\left(\frac{1}{n^{3}} \right). $$

Therefore we have the following estimate:

$$ \int_{0}^{x} \frac{dt}{1+(t \cos t)^{2}} = \log x + O(1). $$