# Does the integral $\int_0^{\infty} {1 \over {1+x^2 \cdot \sin^2 x}}$converge?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Does the integral $\int_0^{\infty} {1 \over {1+x^2 \cdot \sin^2 x}}$ converge?

**What I tried:**

- substituting $x \cdot \sin x$ with $t$ and transforming into arctan of something.
- tried to find a multiplication of useful functions in order to do integration by parts.
- I thought about trying to change the integral into a sum if integrals from $k \pi$ to $(k+1) \pi$ but that didn't really give me anything new (except that it produced a series that converges which says nothing for the sum). also, none of the convergence tests that I know gave any conclusive result.

Comment: true, but I know that this function = 1 at the origin.

Answer (score 12):

The following lemma is useful for our aim:

> **Lemma.** For any $a > 0$ we have
>   $$ \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{dx}{1+a^2\sin^2 x} = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{1+a^2}}. $$

Proof of this lemma is straightforward:

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{dx}{1+a^2\sin^2 x}
&= 2 \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{\sec^2 x}{1+(1+a^2)\tan^2 x} \, dx \\
&= 2 \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dt}{1+(1+a^2)t^2} \, dt \qquad (t = \tan x) \\
&= \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{1+a^2}}.
\end{align*}

Now we have

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1+x^2 \sin^2 x}
& \geq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int_{(k-1)\pi}^{k\pi} \frac{dx}{1+(k\pi)^2 \sin^2 x} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{1+k^2\pi^2}} \\
&= \infty.
\end{align*}

**Remarks.**

1. I finally recalled that I posted a solution to an analogous problem. You may check [*this answer*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/564067/does-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-11x-cos-x2-dx-converge/894758#894758). Depending on your flavor, it may look easier to you.
2. This argument also shows that
   $$ \int_{0}^{R} \frac{dx}{1+x^2 \sin^2 x} = \log R + \mathcal{O}(1) \quad \text{as } R \to \infty. $$