# Convergence of improper integral $\int_0^{\infty} 1/(1+x^4 \sin^2(x)) \,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

> I want to determine the convergence of the following improper integral:$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^4\sin^2x}\,dx.$$

I have tried comparison tests for the same.
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^4}\,dx$$ comes out to be convergent while $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{1-x^4}\,dx$$ comes out to be divergent. Thus we can't say actually anything about the convergence of this integral from these two comparisons. How can I proceed from here? Please suggest.

Comment: $0\le \sin^2 x \le 1$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: No, I can't. I wrote it because OP was comparing it with $\dfrac{1}{1-x^4}$ where he was considering $-1\le \sin^2 x$, so that's why I wrote that. I even wrote an answer based on this inequality but later realised $\le1$ also doesn't make it convergent...although I have found some posts related: [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1395495/does-the-integral-int-0-infty-1-over-1x2-cdot-sin2-xconverge) for example.

Comment: @LightYagami. The link you give is very interesting, for sure. Thank you. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: You may check the new link also... it is better than that.

Comment: @LightYagami. This one is more than great ! Thanks again.